# Treeview Checked state Changing?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# windows application there is a Treeview with some roots and child.The Need is that When I checked Parentnode all Childnode under this  must be getselected and when i change checked state of childnode the parent node must be diselect?

Comment: what did you try? you'll need to use reflection to find all childs for a parent, and set `Checked = true` for all of them.

Comment: sorry I can't understant @AmitKumarGhosh

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh This has nothing to do with reflection?  It's a UI problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what you trying to achive. But at least it sounds similar to the Example that is provided in MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck(v=vs.110).aspx